# EntityFramework's object cache. Getting already retrieved objects

Tags: entity-framework

When oject tracking is On, EF remembers all objects it retrieved.
Is there any other way to say EF not to ask DB for the object and make the search in its local cache? I know that GetObjectByKey method looks for the object in memory and only after that in DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query `ObjectStateManager`:

```
var entities = context.ObjectStateManager()
                      .GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Detached) // All attached entities
                      .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity)
                      .OfType<YourEntityType>()
                      .Where(...);
```